# How to access IDs for components within ngFor directive?

Tags: angular

I apologise if this is a duplication, but I'm finding it difficult to get an answer as I'm not sure I'm asking the right question.

I want to draw a little svg bar (multiple times) as part of an ngFor.

Let's say, I have...

**list.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-list',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">
            <app-svgbar [value]="someNumber"></app-svgbar>
        </div>`
})

export class ListComponent {

    items: number[] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

}
```

**svgbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as SVG from 'svg.js';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-svgbar',
    template: `<div id="barID"></div>`
})

export class SvgSingleBarComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() value: number;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.drawSvg(this.value)
    }

    drawSvg( value ) {
        let draw = SVG('barID').size(10, 10) // This is my problem
        draw.rect(value, 10)
        .fill('#000')
    }
}
```

When this runs, it creates all of my svg elements in the first instance of the `id="barID"`

I'm not sure of the correct way to go about something like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Plnkr link](https://embed.plnkr.co/lqEdlw0uo7P1bqb8w6sT/)

Comment: Sooo.. what's the issue? This will create SVG's which will all have the same ID, that doesn't seem correct

Comment: Whats the issue here ?you need different ids for each or draw.rect(value, 10) function is assigning the same value for all ten elements ?

Comment: Ten instances of `<div id="barID"></div>` are created, but all ten SVGs are drawn in the first.

So, I was wondering how to generate unique IDs or if there was some sort of encapsulation that could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is how you are using the SVG lib.

This is your Plunker, working: https://plnkr.co/edit/lqEdlw0uo7P1bqb8w6sT?p=preview

You don't need and index to track the element to achieve this.
Just add the the `nativeElement` to the `SVG` lib usage.

This code will do the trick.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, NgZone, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { id } from "@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/utils";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-svg',
  template: `<div id="bar-{{index}}"></div>`,
  styles: []
})
export class SVGComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() value: number;
  @Input() index: number;

  constructor(public ngZone: NgZone, public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.drawSVG()
  }

  drawSVG() {
    let id = 'bar-' + this.index;
    // console.log('id: ',id);
    // console.log('value: ',this.value);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      console.log(id);
      let draw = SVG(this.elementRef.nativeElement).size(100, 10)
      draw.rect(10*this.value,10)
      .radius(4)
      .fill('#3db8db')  
    });
  }

}
```

The `NgZone` is just to be sure that angular will render the changes of your third party lib.

Comment: Perhaps my question is irrelevant considering the time lapse between when this issue was raised and today, but doesn't angular recommend against using .nativeElement to access a DOM element because of a security risk?

Comment: @user6860460 the recomendation is to don't allow a bypass of the DomSanitizer. For example when someone wants to render a variable with html in it, they have to bypass the DomSanitizer to render that and that is a security risk. The recomendation is to use the `Renderer2` class to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in an `@Input()` for the index of the SVG, and you can concatenate that to the ID to make it unique. Either that, or generate a random string for the ID on each SVG component.

Example of concatenation:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-svgbar',
    template: `<div id="barID-{{index}}"></div>`
})
export class SvgSingleBarComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() index: number;
    @Input() value: number;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.drawSvg(this.value)
    }

    drawSvg( value ) {
        let draw = SVG('barID-' + this.index).size(10, 10) // This is my problem
        draw.rect(value, 10)
        .fill('#000')
    }
}
```

And in your loop on the parent component, be sure to pass in the index:

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <app-svgbar [value]="someNumber" [index]="i"></app-svgbar>
    </div>`
```

---

If you don't want to deal with indexes, you can just set a random generated ID for each SVG component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-svgbar',
    template: `<div id="{{randomID}}"></div>`
})
export class SvgSingleBarComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() value: number;

    randomID: string = (Math.random() * 1000000000).toString();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.drawSvg(this.value)
    }

    drawSvg( value ) {
        let draw = SVG(this.randomID).size(10, 10) // This is my problem
        draw.rect(value, 10)
        .fill('#000')
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You may not even need an ID here. Just inject `ElementRef` and use that for your unique element access.

```
import { ..., ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

drawSvg( value ) {
    let draw = SVG(this.el.nativeElement).size(10, 10)
}
```

Do the above and everything seems to work perfectly with no errors. I would show a Plnkr example, but it wouldn't let me save your Plnkr since it was an embed link.

Comment: That was my initial thought on how to implement it but it didn't work. I've fleshed out a plnkr showing the issue. [Plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/lqEdlw0uo7P1bqb8w6sT/)

Comment: Problem may be because `drawSvg` is called before the index is passed in as @Input by Angular, which means your SVG function may not be able to find the svg. Also, your plnkr is giving this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null`.

Comment: You may not even need an ID here; could just use elementRef. Working a solution for you.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Cheers! @camaron just got there first. Really appreciate the help!